# Decoding Multiple JSON URLs into a Single Class

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I'm attempting to decode multiple JSON URLs into a class. Since I'm using an API, I have no control over the fact that the JSON data is split into two URLs. Here is the problem statement:

1. I have a class called `Student`
2. JSON URL `student_info.json` contains a dictionary with all students and the `Student` instance constants `A`, and `B`.
3. JSON URL `student_status.json` contains `Student` instance variables `C`, `D`, and `E`.

I need to do the following:

1. Retrieve the dictionary of students from `student_info.json` to populate a collection of Students and instantiate them with attributes `A` and `B`.
2. Save this `Student` collection so that it is accessible throughout the rest of the app's lifecycle.
3. Retrieve the dictionary of student information from `student_status.json` and populate `Student` instance variables `C`, `D`, and `E` for each student in the collection.
4. From time to time, update the collection of students (in case any were dropped or added).
5. From time to time, update variables `C`, `D`, and `E` for each student in the collection.

Here are some example files:

**File**:

```
student_info.json
```

**Content**:

```
{
"last_updated": 1535936693,
"tyl": 10,
"data": {
  "students": [
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "name": "John Appleseed",
    },
    {
      "student_id": "2",
      "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

**File**:

```
student_status.json
```

**Content**:

```
{
"last_updated": 1535936693,
"tyl": 10,
"data": {
  "students": [
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "number_of_classes": "10",
      "GPA": "2.87",
      "tuition_due": "237.33"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "2",
      "number_of_classes": "10",
      "GPA": "2.87",
      "tuition_due": "237.33"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

**File**

```
Student.swift
```

**Content**

```
class Student {
  var student_id: Int
  var name: String
  var numberOfClasses: Int?
  var gpa: Double?
  var tuitionDue: Double?
}
```

Comment: What you need is to request your second url data on completion of the first one, once you get all the data needed you can initialize your object with it

Comment: Btw What is your question? Don't you think that's too broad as it is? Note that SO it is not a coding writing service. You should break down your question and show what you have tried and the issues you are facing in each  step (preferably divided into multiple questions)

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for your response. I appreciate that the request as written might appear too general at first glance. The reason I kept it general is because I'm not looking for code-writing to code this functionality, but rather a strategy to implement it. I'm not sure if it's possible/best practice to create and update an instance of a class using the `Codable` protocol in two phases (the first phase with the first JSON URL and the second phase with the second JSON URL). My question is how do I use the Codable protocol to create+update an object using multiple JSON URLs.